# jQuery load() method not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am printing the ajax html response to div element **like-div** but the ajax html response is not working.

**index.php**

```
  <?php
$res_code = '6754567435';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
ul.social-icon > li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.social-icon li a.like').click(function()
    { 
        var track = <?php echo $res_code; ?> ;
        $(".like-div").load("remove.php?keyword=delete&trackid="+track);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="social-icon">
              <li><a class="like" href="#123">Like</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="like-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to diaply the ajax response in div **like-div** on clicking the hyperlink **Like** but this is not showing anything in the div trait.

**remove.php**

```
   <?php
    $keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
    $trackid = $_REQUEST['trackid'];

    if($trackid != '')
{
    echo "hello";
}
    ?>
```

**remove.php** is the page from where response will come on sending the request. what could be the reason that it is not showing the response in div?

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: try adding quotes `var track = '"' + <?php echo $res_code; ?> + '"' ;`

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel the click

```
$('ul.social-icon li a.like').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Also I would do

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.social-icon li a.like').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".like-div").load("remove.php?keyword=delete&trackid=<?php echo $res_code; ?>");
  });
});
```

Comment: OP's anchor is using a hash so the ajax request shouldn't abort upon clicking, unless there is some certain browsers that will do that.

Comment: I have to admit I have not tested all browsers, but it is good practice to cancel an event that would reload the page.